# WCF duplex scenario - notifying server of client errors

Tags: wcf, asynchronous, duplex

In a client server WCF duplex scenario, what is the recommended way to let the server know that an error occurred on the client side? Let's say that the server notifies one of the clients that it needs to perform a certain operation and an exception is being thrown on the client side.

On the callback interface, I have something like this

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
void Work(...);
```

What's the best approach:

1. Implement a `NotifyServer(int clientId, string message)` message that the client can call to let the user know that the requested operation failed,
2. If I set `IsOneWay = false` on the operation contract, would I have to call every client on  a `BackgroundWorker` thread in order to keep the UI responsive?
3. Implementing async operations on the server? How will this work? I can generate async operation on the client, will I have to use the same pattern (`BeginWork`, `EndWork`) for the client callback method?

Can't think of anything else, because throwing a `FaultException` on the client side when `IsOneWay = true` will not work.

Any advice?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ad 1. That is one way of doing it... recommended if the Work() may take unpredictable amount of time and you do not want your server thread hanging on that call.

Ad 2. You should always perform WCF operations in the background worker and never inside the UI thread.. If you set IsOneWay=False then obviously Work() method will block on the server until it has finished executing on the remote client and returns results. However even if you set isOneWay=true the method will still block on the low-level WCF communication. If WCF connection is dropped, this can be a long time, before you get notified.

Ad 3.
The pattern is up to you. 
Example: [MSDN: OperationContractAttribute.AsyncPattern Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute.asyncpattern.aspx)

No best solution exists. It all depends on your setup (classes, threads, etc). The WCF layer you code should be easy and convenient to use - that is the main guide line.